# xorrisofs : bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Tags: bash

I'm trying make a `.iso` file using `xorrisofs`, but I'm getting error like this :

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Command I'm using :

```
xorrisofs -o system-($arch).iso     \
      -b boot/isolinux/isolinux.bin \
      -c boot.cat                   \
      -no-emul-boot                 \
      -boot-load-size 4             \
      -boot-info-table              \
      -joliet -l -R                 \
      iso($arch)
```

Comment: Where did you find this command?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams In here : https://github.com/dracos-linux/base-iso , on file `README`

Answer (score 3):

The parenthesis by themselves are used to group commands (in a subshell), e.g.

```
(echo foo ; echo bar) | cat -n
```

But that doesn't make sense in the middle of a command line, so Bash takes it as an error. (Other shells treat it differently, zsh takes that as a glob, ksh93 just leaves the parenthesis as-is and expands the variable.)

They probably meant either `"system-${arch}.iso"` to take the value of the variable `arch`; or `"system-$(arch).iso"` to run a command `arch` and use its output on the command line. Both of those should be used within quotes.

If you want literal parenthesis (and the variable expansion), again quote the whole string: `"system-($arch).iso"`.

Same for the `($arch)` at the last line.